# jQuery selector for form controls that are nullified, deselected, or unchecked

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core

In my ASP.Net CORE MVC view form, there are checkboxes, radio groups, select dropdowns, textareas, text inputs, and number inputs. Each is a table record in database.  Each has a "data-oldvalue" attribute with the original value, and "data-useranswerid" of the record key when the control is rendered.  When the form is submitted, if a control nullified (null, unchecked, or deselected), the record matching the recordID needs to deleted. I am using the following jQuery selector to select target elements, but it only select non-null controls.  How can I select those form controls? Thanks so much.

```js
const target = $(':checked, :selected, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="number"]');
target.each(function() {
      const $this: any = $(this);
      let newValue: string = '';
      if ($this.val()) {
        newValue = $this.val().toString();
      }

      let oldValue: string = '';
      if ($this.data('oldvalue')) {
        oldValue = $this.data('oldvalue').toString();
      }

      if (newValue !== oldValue) { ....logic to delete or insert record here....
      }
    }
```

Here is an example of the checkbox in the form.

```html
@model List<ChoiceViewModel>
@{
  string originalValue = string.Empty;
  ChoiceViewModel checkedValue = Model.Where(x => x.Selected).FirstOrDefault();
  if (checkedValue != null)
  {
    originalValue = checkedValue.ChoiceID.ToString();
  }
}
<div class="flex-start-column-wrap">
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <div class="mdc-form-field">
      <div class="mdc-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control persistable"
               name="@(item.QuestionKey)-@(item.ChoiceID)" id="@(item.QuestionKey)-@(item.ChoiceID)"
               value="@item.ChoiceID" checked="@item.Selected"
               data-questionid="@item.QuestionID" data-questionkey="@item.QuestionKey" data-userid="@ViewData["UserID"]"
               data-useranswerid="@item.UserAnswerID" data-oldvalue="@originalValue">
        
        <span asp-validataion-for="@(item.QuestionKey)-@(item.ChoiceID)"></span>
        
        <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
          <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
               viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"
                  fill="none"
                  d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"></path>
          </svg>
          <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-checkbox__ripple"></div>
      </div>
      <label for="@(item.QuestionKey)-@(item.ChoiceID)">@item.ChoiceDescription</label>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: For your sample,did you mean you could not get the unchecked checkbox?And what did you mean for delete the record?Delete from the database or any other meanings?

Comment: `:checked` means to match all elements that are checked or selected.So you could not get the unchecked and unselected elements.Try to use `input[type="checkbox"]`.

Comment: You may use [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/#input1) and [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo selectors, e.g. `$(':input:not(:checked, :selected)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.  This works for me.  There must be a less convoluted way.

```js
  // find all unchecked (null) persistables ///////////////////////$(':input:not(:checked, :selected)')
  const uncheckedPersistables = $('.persistable', theForm)
    .filter(function () {
      return !this.value;
    });
  console.log('manuallyCreateTheJson2 ::: uncheckedPersistables', uncheckedPersistables);
  uncheckedPersistables.each(function (index, item) {
    const $thisUncheckedPersistable: any = $(this);
    console.log('uncheckedPersistables(' + index + ')', item);
    if ($thisUncheckedPersistable[0].type === 'checkbox' || $thisUncheckedPersistable[0].type === 'radio') {
      const oldValue: string = $thisUncheckedPersistable.data('oldvalue')?.toString();
      let checkboxValue: string = $thisUncheckedPersistable.val(); //get the value attribute of the radio or checkbox

      if (oldValue.indexOf(checkboxValue) !== -1 && !$thisUncheckedPersistable[0].checked) {
        let newValue: string = ''; //assign blank value to signal that this answer ID to be deleted
        let thisAnswer: IUserAnswer = <IUserAnswer>{};
        thisAnswer = createAjaxAnswer($thisUncheckedPersistable, facilityID, facilityRelationshipID, fiscalYear, userID, oldValue, newValue, changedAnswerCount++);
        newAnswers.push(thisAnswer);
      }
    }
  });
```